# I want to retrieve the first and second elements from one argument of \def

Tags: tikz-pgf, definition

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[help lines](0,0)grid(3,3);

    \def\line_segment#1;
        {  
            \draw(#1[0],#1[1])--(2,2);
        }

    \line_segment{1,1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to draw a line segment between (1,1) and (2,2). And I've written the above codes to achieve it. The compilation is done successfully however the actual first coordinate is not correct as from the diagram.

What can I do for next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried almost works. You only have to add some braces, and note that without further ado a macro name cannot contain an underscore.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines](0,0)grid(3,3);

    \def\lineSegment#1;{  
            \draw({{#1}[0]},{{#1}[1]})--(2,2);
        }

    \lineSegment{1,1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course,

```
    \def\lineSegment#1;{  
            \draw(#1)--(2,2);
        }
```

also works, and you could also use pgf keys:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line segment/.code={\draw({{#1}[0]},{{#1}[1]})--(2,2);}]
    \draw[help lines](0,0)grid(3,3);

    \tikzset{line segment={1,1}}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line segment/.code={\draw(#1)--(2,2);}]
    \draw[help lines](0,0)grid(3,3);

    \tikzset{line segment={1,1}}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```